# Nuget package which adds to Application.Resources MergedDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget

**Background**

We use *Nuget packages* in-house as a way to commonize services, library and resources in the menagerie of solutions and projects we have.

However in regards to *WPF* we also have custom font packages, styles (and other *WPF* resources) we would like to merge with the consuming application.

**Desired outcome**

Lets take Fonts as an Example (however this is common to all *Xaml* based resources). We have several custom packs of *Vector Fonts* with *Styles* associated with them. When adding the *Nuget Package* it would be nice to have the *Styles* come in globally somehow (instead of adding a `MergedDictionary` reference to each page or adding a line to `Application.Resouces`) i.e

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I've seen solutions for this with Asp.net (using app_startup) and also people who are using post build events (which seem a little flaky).

**Potential Solution**

A solution i have been thinking about, is to make a simple Interface/Class, Tag *WPF* global resources in our *Nuget Libraries*, and using reflection and an *Dependency Walker* to prob *Assemblies* looking for said Interface/Class. Which in turn adds them to the `Application.Resources` in code i.e

```
...
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
...
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Obviously we would still have to kick this off per application somehow, however it would solve the problem of having to track down `Nuget` resources and manually adding them to each Page *Xaml* or `Application.Resources`.

**My Question**

Is there a way to solve problem out of the box? Is there some plumbing i can use with *Nuget* and *WPF* that could achieve this already that i'm not aware of?